# Way to get logged in user in Expression Engine?

Tags: expressionengine

I am using [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com) in part of a site I am developing and other parts are just using my own PHP.  My question is how can I tell who the user is logged in as on a non-EE page?  I have access to the EE cookies and the EE database but couldn't find a way to use these values to figure out who the user is.  I have a list of all the cookie keys/values at: http://andrewgjohnson.com/cookies.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the exp_uniqueid cookie value should match the unique_id field in the exp_members table.